# Apache 2.4 Web Based Console

Tags: apache-2.4

I read in a news article about apache httpd 2.4 being released with the feature to configure servers via web console rather than text file. I looked in the documentation and couldnt find anything around this. Does anyone know how to set this up? or where

Basically I have multiple web servers and  want to be able to deploy a new web server with little config as possible. Whats the best way to do this? copy the config file around or will apache 2.4 help at all?

> "One of the problems with cloud environments with the 2.2 releases is
>   that admins would have to spin up Web servers manually. With 2.4,
>   Apache can be configured to automatically pull in a new Web server to
>   handle additional load. In addition, admins now have a Web-based
>   interface to add and configure Apache clusters – rather than having to
>   tweak text-based configurations by hand."
>
> http://www.readwriteweb.com/cloud/2012/02/apache-24-sets-sights-on-cloud.php

Comment: I really hope this is true!  By the way, doesn't IIS already have a web based config editor?

Comment: I'd say "the best way to do this" for easy deploys of new servers would be a configuration management tool like Puppet or Chef - but I'm just as curious as you on what feature that article is referring to; I can't find anything.